# No route matches [GET] "staticpage.html"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, static-pages

I am trying to setup a new static and later dynamic page.

Inside `app/controllers/` I created `detailpages_controller.rb`. Inside I have:

```
class DetailPagesController < ApplicationController    
 def show
  render
 end
end
```

Then, on `config/routes.rb`I have:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   root 'welcome#index'
   DetailPagesController.action_methods.each do |action|
    get "/#{action}", to: "detailpages##{action}", as: "#{action}_page"
  end
end
```

On `app/viewes/pages` there is a `detailpages.html.erb` file that just contains a `<h2>Hello World</h2>`

When I go to `http://localhost:3000/detailpages.html` I get:

> No route matches [GET] "/detailpages.html"

if I just do `localhost:3000` my `index.html` works perfectly fine but I can't, for my life, add this new page so I can later link to it.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you looping through the action methods?

Comment: I read somewhere that it's smarter than adding a new row manually everytime I get a new action. I will have a few, but I can't get this one to begin with.

Comment: Well, what is your objective with this controller? If you just want to map this static page to the show action you can do `get 'detailpages.html' => 'detail_pages#show', as: :detail_page`

Comment: I still get an error, just a different one: `uninitialized constant DetailPagesController`

Comment: The name of the file is wrong, should be `detail_pages_controller.rb`

Comment: oh ok, that changed the error entirely. So, 2 questions: 1) do I need to always separate words by _ if the Controller has more than 1 word? (i.e. DetailPages = detail_pages and 2) now I have `Missing template detail_pages/show` I thought with a method `def show render :action => :show end` it would be enough but I'm missing something, could you point me to docs that talk about this? And thank you!

Comment: Yes, each word is separated with `_`, called snake case if I remember correctly. You will need to add the template `app/views/detail_pages/show.html.erb`

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: got it to work. Thank you! If you want to write it as an answer, I'll mark you as the right one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map to the `detailpages.html` with

```
get 'detailpages.html' => 'detail_pages#show', as: :detail_page
```

Also you need to edit the name of your `DetailPagesController`, it should be `detail_pages_controller.rb`. Every word is separated with `_`, called snake casing.

You will also need a corresponding view, placed in `app/views/detail_pages/show.html.erb`